# Cannot access SQL Server Express 2005 database in VMWARE

Tags: vmware, virtualization, sql-server-express

I'm running an SQL Server express 2005 database inside a guest OS that I'm trying to connect to via a application running on the host. However, I'm not able to connect to the database (I can connect to the database if I run the application inside the guest OS).

Both operating systems are Windows XP 64.

I'm using bridged networking mode, but it doesn't seem to work in NAT or Host-only mode.

Firewalls are switched off on both the guest and host.

I'm able to ping the guest OS successfully. Port 1434 is open on the guest.

I'm new to virtualization, so it might be just something simple that I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have configured Sql Express to accept remote connections haven't you? Networking protocols are disabled by default in Sql Express and you have to enable them to remotely access the database. You'll need to [configure Sql Express to accept remote connections](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlexpress/archive/2005/05/05/415084.aspx)

Comment: D'oh! It turns out I hadn't actually configured SQL Server Express properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and found out all I had to do was add a route so that the VM could get to the host.  So inside of the VM open up a console and add a route to the host PC.  You will have to slightly modify this to match your settings.  I have bolded the settings that you will more then likely need to change.

route ADD **172.16.0.0** MASK 255.255.255.0 **172.16.0.1**

Also if you are using SQL Server Express, I have generally seen it requires ip\SQLEXPRESS or name\SQLEXPRESS

Answer (score 0):

"D'oh! It turns out I hadn't actually configured SQL Server Express properly. Thanks. – SuperFurryToad Aug 3 '09 at 16:06"

You maybe didn't. I know I had SQL server set up correctly as I was running queries fropm a remote client just hours before I started migrating the physical box to a virtual instance.

This is the first real quirk I have noticed and the option had been reset.